# Postgres: Preventing Delete if an association exists

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way in postgres to prevent a record from being deleted if there exists another record that contains it's foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict Deletes with the second line in this example SQL

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    product_no integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
    quantity integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_no, order_id)
);
```

Comment: awesome, thats the word I am looking for 'Restrict'. thank you!

Comment: @stellard: you can leave out `RESTRICT` as that is the default.